# React js list of sobject is not displaying after fetching the list from controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am calling remote action(salesforce feature) from `componentWillMount` method

```
componentWillMount()
  {
    this.props.dispatch(qryAccts());
    console.log(this.props);
  }
```

and my action is

```
export function qryAccts()
{
  return dispatch => {
    ResponsiveCtrl.getAccts(function(r, e) {
      console.log('------26----',r);
      dispatch(recAccts(r))
    },{escape:false});
  }
}
```

[image]
in this line no 26 I am getting list of objects but in my dom it is not displaying on load of this page

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Accounts</h1>
        <ul>
         {this.props.accts && this.props.accts.map((v,i) => <li key={i}><input style={{width:'500px'}} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event,i)} value={v.Name}/></li>) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any guess what is the issue here.

complete code

```
// ------------------------------------
// Constants
// ------------------------------------


export const RECEIVED_ACCTS = 'RECEIVED_ACCTS';
export const UPSERT_ACCTS = 'UPSERT_ACCTS';
export const ADD_ACCT = 'ADD_ACCT';
export const UPDATE_ACCTS = 'UPDATE_ACCTS';


// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export function recAccts(accts) {
  return{
    type: RECEIVED_ACCTS,
    accts: accts
  }
}

export function qryAccts()
{
  return dispatch => {
    ResponsiveCtrl.getAccts(function(r, e) {
      console.log('------26----',r);
      dispatch(recAccts(r))
    },{escape:false});
  }
}

export function upsertAccts(acctStore) {
  return dispatch => {
    ResponsiveCtrl.upsertAccts(acctStore, function(r, e) {
      dispatch(recAccts(r))
    },{escape:false});
  }
}

export function addAcct() {
  return {
    type: ADD_ACCT
  }
}

export function updateAccts(name,index) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACCTS,
    acctName:name,
    listIndex:index
  }
}

/*  This is a thunk, meaning it is a function that immediately
    returns a function for lazy evaluation. It is incredibly useful for
    creating async actions, especially when combined with redux-thunk!

    NOTE: This is solely for demonstration purposes. In a real application,
    you'd probably want to dispatch an action of COUNTER_DOUBLE and let the
    reducer take care of this logic.  */



// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = ;

//Reducer function
export function accts(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('==action===',action);
  console.log('==initialState===',initialState);
  console.log('==state===',state);
  switch (action.type) {
  case RECEIVED_ACCTS:
  //Return the Accouts we receive from Salesforce
    state = action.accts;
    return state;
  case UPDATE_ACCTS:
  //Update our array at the specific index
    var newState = state.slice();
    newState[action.listIndex].Name = action.acctName;
    return newState;
  case ADD_ACCT:
  //Add a new Account to our Array
    var newState = state.slice();
    newState.push({Name:""});
    return newState;
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

My HomeView.js

```
export default HomeView

//Import React
import React from 'react'

//Import Redux Components
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

//Import Action
import { addAcct, upsertAccts, qryAccts, updateAccts } from '../../Counter/modules/counter';

class HomeView extends React.Component {
  constructor (props)
  {
    super(props);


  }
  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.props.dispatch(qryAccts());
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  //Perform Upsert Actions
  upsertAccts(e)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(upsertAccts(this.props.accts))
  }

  //Add new Account to the Array
  addAcct(event)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(addAcct());
    console.log('===this.props===',this.props);
  }


  //onChange function to handle when a name is changed
  handleChange(ev,index)
  {
    this.props.dispatch(updateAccts(ev.target.value,index));
  }

  dateChange(e)
  {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Accounts</h1>
        <ul>
         {this.props.accts && this.props.accts.map((v,i) => <li key={i}><input style={{width:'500px'}} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event,i)} value={v.Name}/></li>) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Connects Redux State to React, Injects reducer as a property
//export default Page1Demo;
export default connect(state => ({ accts: state.accts }))(HomeView);
```

Comment: Definitely not enough info. What is going on in your reducers? Is you data saved successfully in redux store? How do you connect your component to redux store? What actual properties is component receives?

Comment: @trashgenerator I have updated the question. check now

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying state inside reducer here `state = action.accts;` and here `newState[action.listIndex].Name = action.acctName`.

Probably your problems because of that.

If not, check using `redux-devtools` that new objects are actually saved in state. Then using `react devtools` check that correct data is passed to `HomeView`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. If i just keep the RECEIVED_ACCTS and remove all other still the data is not displaying on page.

Comment: RECEIVED_ACCTS  case also has error. try: 
`case RECEIVED_ACCTS:
    return action.accts;`